# What is the best way to board interior of a large shed?

Tags: insulation, shed

I have a large shed/workshop which I want to board with OSB/Ply to make the interior more usable for hanging things from the walls and to just generally make it "nicer" inside. I'm not fussed about packing it out with insulation and there is no water making it inside currently.

Am I ok to just attach boards to the framing or do I need to put some sort of moisture barrier in place no matter what?

Comment: For outdoor use, I'd just leave a 1" airflow gap at the top and bottoms.  Let it dry out naturally

Comment: @ChrisCudmore
may want to put screening over the 1in gaps or use soffit vents, to keep nesting critters out

Comment: Personally, I would avoid OSB and use plywood. I like to cover the ply with smooth tempered hardboard for a nice clean look and for durability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an uninsulated shed I usually find exposed studs more useful for hanging/storing most tools, with the occasional board where that's not true.

Anyway, for a dry, uninsulated, unheated shed, you need not do anything more than nail (or screw) it to the framing. I would actively avoid @Chris Cudmore's "gap" suggestion, however, since it sounds like making exceedingly convenient rodent housing, to me. I'd keep it as tight as possible and might even caulk any unavoidable gaps to make life more difficult for rodents and insects (could be delightful and hard-to-get-at wasp habitat, too.)